# Solve $x'\cos^2t+x\ln{x}=x\sin{t}\cdot te^{\tan t}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Solve $$x'\cos^2t+x\ln{x}=x\sin{t}\cdot te^{\tan t}$$

Hint is to find and use substitution $u(x)=\dots$

I try $u=\ln x$, then $x=e^u, x'=e^uu'$

And we obtain: $$u'+\frac{u}{\cos^2t}=\frac{\sin t}{\cos^2t}te^{\tan t}$$

So first we solve corresponding homogeneous equation and obtain $u=c\cdot e^{-\tan t}$. We assume that $c=c(t)$ and put it into inhomogeneous equation. The problem is that now we need to solve integral $$c=\int\frac{\sin t}{\cos^2t}te^{2\tan t}$$ and I do not know if it is even solvable.

It would be easier if our equation to solve was $$x'\cos^2t+x\ln{x}=x\sin{t}\cdot te^{-\tan t}$$. But it isn't. So I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: I think the solution looks terrible, should I post you that thing?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner If it's terrible then probably there is some mistake in this task, because it should be solvable. I just wanted to ensure that there is no some better solution I am not aware of. Or I made mistake somewhere, which to my best knowledge is not the case.

Comment: $c=\int t  e^{2\tan t} \tan t \sec t dt $ put $k=\sec t, dk =\sec t \tan t dt$ If this substitution will work $\sec^{-1} k e^{2\sqrt{k^2 -1}}dk$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\ln x$ ,

Then $x=e^u$

$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=e^u\dfrac{du}{dt}$

$\therefore e^u\dfrac{du}{dt}\cos^2t+ue^u=e^u\sin t\cdot te^{\tan t}$

$\dfrac{du}{dt}+u\sec^2t=te^{\tan t}\sec t\tan t$

I.F.$=e^{\int\sec^2t~dt}=e^{\tan t}$

$\therefore\dfrac{d(ue^{\tan t})}{dt}=te^{2\tan t}\sec t\tan t$

$ue^{\tan t}=\int^t\tau e^{2\tan\tau}\sec\tau\tan\tau~d\tau+c$

$\ln x=e^{-\tan t}\int^t\tau e^{2\tan\tau}\sec\tau\tan\tau~d\tau+ce^{-\tan t}$

$x=Ce^{e^{-\tan t}}e^{e^{-\tan t}\int^t\tau e^{2\tan\tau}\sec\tau\tan\tau~d\tau}$

It is wellcome to leave the difficult integrals unsolve when solving the differential equations as solving integrals are not the main points when solving the differential equations.

Comment: OP already did solve the differential equation , Op is asking for the solution of the resulting integral @doraemonpaul